# AttributeError: 'Embedding' object has no attribute 'get_shape' with TensorFlow backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to understand how Embedding layers work with masking (for sequence to sequence regression).

This simple code fails with the error: `AttributeError: 'Embedding' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`. It seems to be true, however I don't know how to solve it. Any hint?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import plot_model

trainExs = np.asarray([ [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]])
trainLabels = np.asarray([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])

print('Examples, shape:', trainExs.shape)
print('Labels, shape:', trainLabels.shape)

W = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
symDim = 3

# E M B E D D I N G S
# symbol_in = Input(shape=(None, 1), dtype='float32', name='symbol_input')
symbol_emb = Embedding(symDim+1, symDim,
                       weights=np.asarray(W), trainable=False, input_length=3)

symbol_dense = Dense(symDim, use_bias=True, name='symbol_dense')(symbol_emb)

output_layer = Dense(symDim, dtype='float32', name='output')(symbol_dense)

# M O D E L
model = Model(inputs=[symbol_emb], outputs=[output_layer])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
# print(model.summary())
```

The full stack trace follows:

```
D:\python\python.exe D:/workspace/TESTS/test/testEMb.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Examples, shape: (2, 3)
Labels, shape: (2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workspace/TESTS/test/testEMb.py", line 21, in <module>
    symbol_dense = Dense(symDim, use_bias=True, name='symbol_dense')(symbol_emb)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 541, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 450, in assert_input_compatibility
    ndim = K.ndim(x)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 479, in ndim
    dims = x.get_shape()._dims
AttributeError: 'Embedding' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

Comment: Can we ask such a question here or now we have to ask on cross-validated please?

Answer (score 5):

You are feeding `symbol_emb` to your model as an input, but `symbol_emb` is the name of your Embedding layer and is not a valid input. Define an input such as:

```
input = Input(shape=input_shape)
symbol_emb = Embedding(symDim+1, symDim,
                       weights=np.asarray(W), trainable=False)(input)

...
...

model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output_layer])
```

Note that you do not need to define `input_length` in `Embedding` this way.

Comment: Thank you michetonu. From the doc, where they say an Embedding layer must be the first layer in the model, I thought I could not add an Input layer before the embedding.

Comment: In this case, what should the input_shape be? Since it receives one number, an index into W...

Comment: What is `input_shape`?

Comment: @Hadij the shape of the input as a tuple (rows, columns)